# Import dependency with bower Ember CLI - could not find module

Tags: node.js, ember.js, module, ember-cli, browserify

I'm trying to use [Markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) in Ember Helper. First I installed it with **Bower** and tried to import it.

```
app.import('bower_components/markdown-it/dist/markdown-it.js');
```

In helper:

```
import MarkdownIt from "markdown-it";
```

This is showing error `Could not find module: markdown-it`. Then I tried to use [Ember-browserify](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify) and install `Markdown-it` via npm. I tried to import it in helper

```
import MarkdownIt from "npm:markdown-it";

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function(input){
    var result = MarkdownIt.render(input);
    return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(result);
});
```

This is showing error `TypeError: a.default.render is not a function`.

I also tried

```
import MarkdownIt from "npm:markdown-it";

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function(input){
    var md = new MarkdownIt();
    var result = md.render(input);
    return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(result);
});
```

This is showing Error: Could not find module `npm:markdown-it` imported from `my-new-app/helpers/format-markdown`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you're trying to use doesn't provide a name for itself when using AMD, so there's no way to `import` it via a name. See https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/770 for more information about this.

It does look like "markdown-it" also exposes itself as a global, so you can always access it that way:

Comment: Thanks, I'll be more careful while opening issues.